# Filtering data over id

Tags: angular

Hello I want to display only the data which includes the userid in the wishlist array. What I am doing wrong?

```
items = { "_id" : ObjectId("58016d54c6622964cc8906be"), "wishlist":[5893278927277749594, 5893278927277749595, 5893278927277749596] "country" : "Ireland" }
```

**Pipe file**

```
import {Pipe} from 'angular2/core';


@Pipe({
  name: 'WishListFilter'
})
export class WishListPipe {

  transform(items, args?): any {
        return items.filter(items => items.wishlist == args.userId);
    }


}
```

**Component file**

```
import { WishListPipe } from './wishlist-pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'wislist',
  pipes: [ WishListPipe ],
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of (items | WishListFilter:this.userId">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  `
})

export class MainSite(){

public userId = '5893278927277749595'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `this` in templates:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of (items | WishListFilter :userId)">{{item}}</li>
```